# Casilla aceptacion LOPD en formulario y php

Tags: php, formularios

tenemos que incluir en el formulario de contacto la casilla de aceptacion de la politica de privacidad , eso en html es sencillo con este codigo

```
<input type="checkbox" name="aceptar_terminos" id="aceptar_terminos" value="aceptar_terminos"  /> He leído y acepto la <a href="#" target="_blank">Política de Privacidad</a>
```

¿Que habria que incluir en el php para que si no se selecciona esa casilla no se pueda proceder a enviar el formulario?

este es el php que tenemos ahora

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'catoira@catoiracamp.es';
$subject = 'Mensaje desde la web'.$field_name;

$body_message = 'De: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Mensaje: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Gracias. Nos pondremos en contacto lo antes posible.');
        window.location = 'contactar-con-catoira-camp-campamento-de-verano.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Hmmm. Algo ha fallado en el formulario de contacto. Mande por favor un correo a catoira@catoiracamp.es');
        window.location = 'contactar-con-catoira-camp-campamento-de-verano.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Proceso a realizar: verificas si el checkbox está marcado a través de javascript en el lado del cliente, por el lado del servidor lo realizas mediante PHP (porque es el lenguaje que veo utilizas en el segmento de código adjuntado). Básicamente es preguntar por la propiedad "checked"  del checkbox. Si agregas el html de tu formulario podríamos ayudarte mejor, no puedo agregar el código "ciegamente" porque no sé como se llama tu botón ni conozco si es tipo submit o envias tus datos a través de AJAX, entre otras cosas relevantes que necesito para poder dar una buena solución a tu pregunta

Comment: Te invito a que coloques tu HTML para poder ayudarte en la brevedad posible. Un saludo

Comment: Desde el php no pero desde el HTML puedes ponerle un required, _Ventajas_: Es una sola palabra dentro del input.                  
_Desventajas_: se puede quitar desde los navegadores.
_Solución alternativa_: Valida los campos por js antes que por php.
_Solución alternativa2_: envía el formulario, pero a una página de validación, guarda todos los datos introducidos en variables por si debes devolverlas. Si el checkbox no está marcado, devuelve a la página anterior y que esta rellene los campos si existen datos en `$_POST`, si no, estarán vacíos (cuando entras de primeras al formulario p.ej)

Comment: Este es el codigo html del formulario

Comment: Perdon , salio mal el mensaje. Este es el codigo html del formulario   <div class="aceptar_terminos_caja">
       <input type="checkbox" name="aceptar_terminos" id="aceptar_terminos" value="aceptar_terminos"  /> He leído y acepto la <a href="aviso-legal-campamento-de-verano-Catoira-Camp.html" target="_blank">Política de Privacidad</a></a>
        </div>
Espero que ahora se vea , gracias

Answer (score 3):

En vez de enviar el formulario al servidor para luego verificar, puedes hacerlo por Javascript del lado del cliente. De ese modo, ahorras cargas innecesarias al servidor.

Para ello, harías que el botón `Enviar` dependa del estado de la aceptación de los términos o no. O sea, mientras no se acepten los términos el botón `Enviar` va a permanecer desactivado y en consecuencia el formulario no se podrá enviar. Si te fijas, es así como suele funcionar.

Se trata simplemente de escuchar el evento `change`  del checkbox de aceptación de términos. La función verificará si el checkbox está seleccionado o no, y en base a eso cambiará o no el estado del botón. Eso ocurre cada vez que el usuario marca o desmarca la casilla, como podrás comprobar.

Sería más o menos así:

```js
document.getElementById("aceptar_terminos").addEventListener('change', checkAccepted);

function checkAccepted(event) {
  var btnEnviar = document.getElementById("btnEnviar");
  console.log(this.checked);
  var isNotChecked = !this.checked;
  btnEnviar.disabled = isNotChecked;

}
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="#">
  <input id="ibxNombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" />
  <br />
  <input id="ibxApellido" type="text" placeholder="Apellido" />
  <br />
  <input id="ibxMail" type="email" placeholder="@email" />
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="aceptar_terminos" id="aceptar_terminos" value="aceptar_terminos" /> He leído y acepto la <a href="#" target="_blank">Política de Privacidad</a>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" disabled>
</form>
```